# Error with passing parameter to component

Tags: laravel

Reading how to make components here
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components
in my Laravel Framework 7.6.2 app I got error :

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $is_auto_hide ]] in class App\View\Components\AppBackendHeader (View:
```

for my first var defined in the component app/View/Components/AppBackendHeader.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class AppBackendHeader extends Component
{

    public $is_auto_hide;

    public $message;
    public function __construct($is_auto_hide, $message)
    {
        $this->is_auto_hide = $is_auto_hide;
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.app-backend-header');
    }
}


calling this component from blade page : 
        <x-app-backend-header is_auto_hide="true" message="message 1234" />


In app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php I added line :

    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::component('app-backend-header', AppBackendHeader::class);
...
```

Calling the template I pass is_auto_hide parameter and it does not looks like misspelling...

I tried to run commands:

```
$ composer dump-autoload 
$ php artisan view:clear
$ php artisan config:cache
```

and it did not help...
What is the problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#passing-data-to-components):

> Component constructor arguments should be specified using camelCase, while kebab-case should be used when referencing the argument names in your HTML attributes.

This means you need:

```
public function __construct($isAutoHide, $message)
{
    $this->is_auto_hide = $isAutoHide;
    $this->message = $message;
}
```

and you should refer to it as:

```
 <x-app-backend-header is-auto-hide="true" message="message 1234" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that camelCase is not recommendation, but strict rule. Is this only feature of components? Are there similar  strict rules in Laravel 6/7 ?

Comment: +1 though this limitation makes no sense. *If* a constructor argument is camel case, *then* it will be converted to kebab. Not sure what why that has to negate the use of underscores, but it did resolve my problem.

Comment: wow you are my savior. saviors save us