# Can multi word variable be passed to blade component?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have created new component using `php artisan make:component Test`.
Now, when creating that component, if I try to pass one word variable everything works fine (`<x-test :testID="'test'"`). But when I try passing it as multi word, separating words by using underscore (`<x-test :test_id="'test'"`), I am facing next error:

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $test_id ]] in class App\View\Components\Test
```

And that class looks like this:

```
class Test extends Component
{
    public $test_id;

    public function __construct($test_id)
    {
        $this->test_id = $test_id;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.test');
    }
}
```

Is this normal behaviour and is it even allowed to use underscore when creating variables inside components?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with passing parameter to component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359801/error-with-passing-parameter-to-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Livewire components do not support the classical `__construct` constructor. Instead you better use the [`mount()` method](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#initializing-properties).

Furthermore you should work with public properties like this

```php
public $test_id;

public function mount()
{
    // properly initialize the var
    $this->test_id = 0;
}
```

and reference (see [Data Binding](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding)) it in your view with

```
<x-test wire.model="test_id"/>
```

I generally would always go for `camelCase` naming, f. ex. `testId`. This is definately fully supported in Livewire (see [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart)).

**Some general hint about naming variables**

What you describe with *one word* and *multi word* variable is named

- camel case, f. ex. `myVariableName`, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)
- snake case, f. ex. `my_variable_name`, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)

Update for **comment component**

```php
class Comments extends Component
{
    public int $postId;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->postId = 0;
    }


    public function render()
    {
        $comments = Comments::where('post_id', $this->postId)->get();

        return view('post.list', [
          'comments' => $comments,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your views you can use something like this.

```
<x-comments :postId="$post->id"/>
```

You don't need to inject it into the `mount` method. Just use the public property.

Comment: Thank you, my bad. What I am really trying to do is next. I am creating a blog and now I need to make it able to put comments on every single post. I want to pass `$post->id` to the component I created `<x-comment :post_id="$post->id" />` (that's the one I called `x-test` up there). So my next question, according to your answer, would be - can I pass parameters to `mount()` function with which I can later initialize the var?

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue. I can't pass in `:dd_array="$dd_color"` to an anonymous blade component,  but passing it like `:ddArray="$dd_color"` works fine.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way it works. Seams like camel case is accepted, but snake case is not